# Thumbnail not working for "Like" Button using Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have added a like button to a page on my site. FB is generating the thumbnail (that I do not want to use) I have used the open graph meta tags AND included the  to the logo that I want to use in the head of my document. I have even reset the size of the image to be a perfect 50x50px. I have used the lint debugger to scrape my page. I have fixed all the errors but it is still not pulling the correct image (although the image in lint is correct). Everything according to the debugger should be working. I have been researching this for days. Will someone please help me with a fix. I am stumped on this one.

This is the page:

http://periopeak.com/periodontal-treatment-faqs/periodontal-treatment.html

Comment: I noticed a tab in yoru og:url.  Try removing that, it may help.